# Windows PowerShell - SqlServerCmdletSnapin100 Error

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I am trying to run the following command through my winodws powershell:

`Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100`

But I get the following error:

[image: ps error]

How can I install `SqlServerCmdletSnapin100`? I can't find anything straight forward. I tried a couple of other commands I found through Google, but they complained about directories not existing !

Comment: What version of Powershell are you using?

Comment: Version 4 @Ramhound

Comment: Update your question.  You have installed the extensions correct?  What `MSSQL Server` version are you trying to connect to?

Comment: Which extensions are we talking about? And how can I check if I have? I'm trying to connect to SQL Server 2012

Comment: [Microsoft® Windows PowerShell Extensions for SQL Server® 2008 R2](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281962(v=sql.105).aspx) and [Servers Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065) and [SQL PowerShell Snapin Problems](http://serverfault.com/questions/543423/sql-powershell-snapin-problems) sounds like you have not actually installed the Snapin thus the reason its indicating you have not installed it.  Be sure to update your question with this relevant information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21672/discussion-between-ciwan-and-ramhound).

Comment: I won't be able to discuss this for another 8 hours.

Comment: Ok no worries, just in case anyone else is reading this, I've installed the Extensions Ramhound linked, but still doesn't show up when I run `Get-PSSnapin -Registered` and I'm running PS as Admin.